# Why does a PySpark UDF that operates on a column generated by rand() fail?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Given the following Python function:

```
def f(col):
    return col
```

If I turn it into a UDF and apply it to a column object, it works...

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

df = spark.range(10)
udf = F.udf(f, returnType=DoubleType()).asNondeterministic()

df.withColumn('new', udf(F.lit(0))).show()
```

...Except if the column is generated by `rand`:

```
df.withColumn('new', udf(F.rand())).show()  # fails
```

*However*, the following two work:

```
df.withColumn('new', F.rand()).show()
df.withColumn('new', F.rand()).withColumn('new2', udf(F.col('new'))).show()
```

The error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o469.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 20.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 20.0 (TID 34, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**Why does this happen, and how can I use a `rand` column expression created within a UDF?**

Comment: Could you try to call rand through lit as `F.lit(F.rand())`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The core issue is that the rand() function on the JVM side depends on a transient rng variable that doesn't survive serialization/deserialization coupled with an `eval` implementation that is null unsafe (defined in RDG class and Rand subclass [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/randomExpressions.scala)). As far as I can tell, `rand()` and `randn()` are the only functions with these specific properties in spark

When you write `udf(F.rand())` spark evaluates this as a single PythonUDF expression and thus serialize the rand() invocation in the command_pickle, losing the initialized transient along the way. This can be observed with the execution plan:

```
df.withColumn('new', udf(F.rand())).explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [id#0L, pythonUDF0#95 AS new#92]
+- BatchEvalPython [f(rand(-6878806567622466209))], [id#0L, pythonUDF0#95]
   +- *(1) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=8)
```

Unfortunately, you're unlikely to overcome this issue without a fix in spark to make the Rand class null safe, however if you just need to generate random numbers you can trivially build your own rand() udf around Python random generator:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
from random import random

def f(col):
    return col

df = spark.range(10)
udf = F.udf(f, returnType=DoubleType()).asNondeterministic()
rand = F.udf(random, returnType=DoubleType()).asNondeterministic()

df.withColumn('new', udf(rand())).show()

+---+-------------------+
| id|                new|
+---+-------------------+
|  0| 0.4384090392727712|
|  1| 0.5827392568376621|
|  2| 0.4249312702725516|
|  3| 0.8423409231783007|
|  4|0.39533981334524604|
|  5| 0.7073194901736066|
|  6|0.19176164335919255|
|  7| 0.7296698171715453|
|  8|  0.799510901886918|
|  9|0.12662129139761658|
+---+-------------------+
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I accidentally awarded the bounty to the wrong answer. I'm asking on meta if it's okay to set a bounty on another question you have answered to award you what you should have gotten; if not, I'll set another one on this question.

Comment: Don't bother, I had fun tracking that bug :)

Comment: I was always wondering how are we guaranteed to get a uniform distribution when we use random.random. Empirically it is (at least whenever I tried), but I'd suppose in theory it can happen that independent executors are initialised with the same seed?